# Overridden CSS Style still effecting element

Tags: html, css, html-lists, selector

I have an imported set of CSS styles. One of those styles is the `list-style-type: none;` that you can see in the screen-shot.

I'm implementing a component right now where I need numbered list items for an `<ol>`. No big deal, I just write a CSS style that's more specific than the imported style, right?

Except for some reason, even though the imported style is overridden, it's still effecting the list when I load the page! Once I disable it in dev-tools, the numbers appear just how I want them, but dev-tools shows that the imported style is crossed out and shouldn't have any effect in the first place.

How is it, that a CSS style that's clearly being overridden is still somehow effecting the element it's targeting?

Any ideas or insights would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you pop your css and html up so we can have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style which sets `list-style-type: none` is applied to `ol` elements **and** `li` elements.

You are overriding it with a more specific selector for the `ol` element, but the `li` element has its defaults overridden so doesn't inherit from the parent `ol`.

This example shows how that works:

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: number;
}

.b {
  list-style-type: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul class=list>
  <li>aaa
  <li class="b">bbb
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. If I change the style I'm trying to apply to ol, ul, li then it works. Just wondering if there's a better way to write the CSS so that I don't need to have pointless selectors in the file.